What is written on this postcard from about 1945 or earlier?
the front part of the postcard

the whole postcard

The German text

the second part of the postcard


Why do you think it's from 1945? There's a date on it from 1907?

great-grandfather said that he brought the postcard in 1945 from Berlin after the end of the war. that's why I thought she was no younger than 1945. I didn't realize that the postcard was so old. I added the second part of this postcard.

I added a photo of the whole postcard

Wouldn't it have been possible to take photos that are in focus?


Templin, 1.10.07


Lieber Cousin!
Die besten Glück- und Segenswünsche zu deinem Geburtstag senden mit den herzlichsten Grüßen an dich und deine[r] lieben Frau
Euer alter Cousin und Cousine
E u. L Voht

So, obviously a birthday card to a cousin. Templin, where the card was apparently sent from, is a town in Brandenburg halfway between Berlin and the Baltic Sea.

I am reading "Voht" as the name.

@ccprog Could be - On second thought, I'll change it

@ccprog I think a more likely reading is "Voss": 1. "Voht", though not unheard of, is an extremely uncommon surname vis à vis "Voss"; 2. The proper name and initials (just as the proper name "Templin") are written, as usual, in Antiqua, which rules out the "long" character being a Kurrent "h". What's left? A long "s" in Antiqua followed by a normal "s" (what would be the combination long+round "s" in Kurrent). --> Voss

@marquinho The frontside now posted proves the extra stroke above the end of the word and the dot after the name are intentional. Any idea what that could represent?

@marquinho afaik the combination of long+round s was used in German Latin script (for names and places) to indicate the Ligatur "ß" - so it's "Voß"

Transcript of the second part:

Herrn
Förster a. D. C. Voß
Hermersdorf bei
Trebnitz i. d. M. an der Ostbahn
frei.

Förster a. D., Förster außer Dienst, is a retired forrest warden. C. is the initial of his first name.
The last name is interpreted as ending with ß. According to the Duden entry here, in latin script there was an old form of writing ß as ſs

In der Schreibform, die in der älteren handſchriftlichen Lateinſchrift für ß üblich war, ſtellt der erste Teil des Zeichens eine Zierform des langen ſ dar, kein h in der deutſchen Schreibſchrift.

For the word "frei" in the last line, I think Arsak's idea is right, and it refers to postage not to be payed.

As I commented on the other answer, I think the name is "Voß" and we see the combination of long and round s to indicate the "ß" in latin script. In addition: I think the last word is "frei" (maybe paying postage was not necessary for this card?)

@Arsak "frei" seems to be right, edited. As for the name, I remain unconvinced. I have never seen a ß written that way.

There was a reddit post about the same issue some days ago. One commenter there posted this link to an old Duden entry that covers this (in section C.c.)

@Arsak The "old Duden entry". That is convincing.

@Arsak Excellent find, very convincing.

Also see the Wikipedia entry with an explanatory grafic

And the ultimate proof: an autograph by J. W. Goethe: third stanza, second line: "Doch du weißt mich zu enwirren"
